# Extração de dados com Python e envio automático de email com as informações obtidas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Amigos,

A parte de extração de dados está funcionando e o envio de email também em parte.

Eu gostaria que a mesma informação que imprimo em tela e com a mesma formatação (pulando linha etc)) fosse enviada como a parte da mensagem do email.
Gostaria de gravar o  mesmo que foi impresso em tela acima e depois enviar por email como **corpo da mensagem** do email e não anexo.

A ideia seria jogar as informações no arquivo lista.txt e depois copiá-las para o corpo do email. A parte de pegar o mesmo que foi impresso em tela e jogar como **corpo da mensagem** do email é o que não funciona. Poderiam ajudar?

Outra dúvida: como modularizar o programa abaixo em 2 arquivos, por exemplo?
Um com a parte de extratir as informações do site e a outra com o envio de email?

```
import os
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
###########################################################

import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import datetime


url = "http://www.purebhakti.com/resources/vaisnava-calendar-mainmenu-71.html"

url_post = 'http://www.purebhakti.com/component/panjika'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'}
payload = {'action': 2, 'timezone': 23, 'location': 'Rio de Janeiro, Brazil        043W15 22S54     -3.00'}

req = requests.post(url_post, headers=headers, data=payload)
soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
eles = soup.select('tr td')
dates = (' '.join(d.select('b')[0].text.strip().split()) for d in eles if d.has_attr('class'))
#events = (' '.join(d.text.split()) for d in eles if not d.has_attr('class'))
events = ((d.text) for d in eles if not d.has_attr('class'))
calendar = dict(zip(dates, events))

#data_hoje = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime() ) #data de hoje
data_desejada=time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime(time.time() + (3600 * 24 * 2))) # daqui a 2 dias
print ("Prezados devotos, ")
print()
print("No dia %s, teremos o(s) seguinte(s) evento(s) no Calendario Vaisnava: " %(data_desejada))
print()
if(data_desejada in calendar):
    print(calendar[data_desejada],end = "" )
else:
    print('nenhum evento para hoje')
print()
print("Para mais detalhes acessem: %s " %(url))
print()
print("Jay Radhe!")



# esta parte nao funciona
#Gostaria de gravar o  mesmo que foi impresso em tela acima e depois enviar #por email como mensagem e não anexo

##arq = open('/home/gopala/Desktop/lista.txt', 'w')
##texto = """
##Prezados devotos,
##
##No dia %s, teremos o(s) seguinte(s) evento(s) no Calendario Vaisnava:  %(data_desejada))
##
##"""
##arq.write(texto)
##
##arq.close()
##



####parte envio email
COMMASPACE = ', '

def main():
    sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
    gmail_password = 'senhalegal'
    recipients = ['destino@gmail.com']

    # Create the enclosing (outer) message
    outer = MIMEMultipart()
    outer['Subject'] = 'data no calendario Vaisnava'
    outer['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(recipients)
    outer['From'] = sender
    outer.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'

    # List of attachments
    attachments = ['/home/gopala/Desktop/16839680_10212563027937627_634163502_n.jpg','/home/gopala/Desktop/lista.txt']

    # Add the attachments to the message
    for file in attachments:
        try:
            with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
                msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
                msg.set_payload(fp.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(msg)
            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(file))
            outer.attach(msg)
        except:
            print("Unable to open one of the attachments. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
            raise

    composed = outer.as_string()

    # Send the email
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:
            s.ehlo()
            s.starttls()
            s.ehlo()
            s.login(sender, gmail_password)
            s.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
            s.close()
        print("Email sent!")
    except:
        print("Unable to send the email. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resposta 1:** Formatação de strings

Você poderia usar uma string formatadora e deixar somente os espaços para as variáveis juntamente com as quebras de linha. Por exemplo.

```
string_envio = "Prezados devotos, "
string_envio += "\n"

if(data_desejada in calendar):
    string_envio += "No dia {}, teremos o(s) seguinte(s) evento(s) no Calendario Vaisnava: "
    string_envio += "\n"
    string_envio += calendar[data_desejada]
else:
    string_envio += "nenhum evento para hoje"

string_envio += "\n"
string_envio += "Para mais detalhes acessem: {}"
string_envio += "Jay Radhe!".format(url,data_desejada)
```

Com isso a string já teria todas as quebras de linha e só os espaços com as variáveis.

Bastando passar como mensagem , sem a necessidade de criar anexo.

**Resposta 2.** Modularização

*Módulos* : Busca , Envio

> Aqui poderia usar tanto função como classes; vou optar por funções.

**Arquivo email.py:**

```
conexao = conectar_email(login,senha) # retornando um objeto de login pronto para enviar emails
conexao.enviar(para=email_destino,titulo=titulo_da_mensagem,corpo=mensagem _formatada_anteriormente)
```

Deixando toda a complexidade de conexão dentro das funções.

**Arquivo busca.py**

```
def request(url,options)
```

**Options** sendo um dicionário geral com os headers que forem passados e a função retornando o html da página requisitada.

```
def find(html,element_procurado)
```

Aqui passaria todo o html lido pelo **request** e também o elemento desejado lá dentro, retornando a parde do html desejado.

```
def parse(element)
```

Aqui seria feito todo o scrapping realmente , mas só do elemento procurado , já que teria passado por todo um processamento anterior.
E retornaria alguma estrutura de dados que você quisesse , por exemplo uma lista com as dadas , um dicionário com a chave sendo o dia e os valores os eventos.. ai você decide.

Usando assim:

```
requisicao = request(sua_url,headers)
elemento = find(requisicao,'tr td')
conteudo = parse(elemento) # retornando a estrutura.
```

E finalmente jogando esse conteúdo dentro da string cada um nos seus lugares e passando para a função de enviar no parâmetro do corpo.

Eliminando ( pelo menos agora ) o uso das libs de anexo.